# External process execution argument issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to send commands to RDP connections from a C# console application using `PsExec`, this is the command

```
PsExec.exe //1.2.3.4 -u administrator -p secredpassword -c RemoteAppExe.exe
```

wich works perfectly, runs `RemoteAppExe.exe` on that system, the problem is that within C# it dosen't work, here is my code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"PsExec.exe";
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "//1.2.3.4 -u administrator -p secredpassword -c RemoteAppExe.exe"; //argument
pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
pProcess.Start();
string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

What is the problem? I assume it might be the fact that arguments are not properly escaped.

Any ideeas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can `psexec.exe` be executed from any folder? or just from a specific one? If so, try adding `pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.

Comment: from any directory. i tried with ` pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".";` , no result, it just showing me the help, as if i runned it without parameters, or invalid parameters ... what to do? i also made a script with `PHP` using `EXEC`and it is working smootly ... why not C#? what is  the problem?

Comment: Did you try running it without all the lines that hide the window?Just with the filename & arguments parameters? Or maybe it has to do with administrative rights. Try running Visual Studio with administrative rights.

Comment: i run it from CMD, it is just ignoring arguments, i runned CMD as administrator, i runned command normally, it works, only thing that does not work is the C# ...

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\1.2.3.4 -u administrator -p secredpassword -c RemoteAppExe.exe";
```

Changing the argument line made the code work for me.

Comment: dosent work, i tried `@"\\....` and `@"//...` , just printing the help, as if i runned without any parameter ...

Comment: I also moved `PsExec.exe` from `System32` to a different folder, because when the `PsExec.exe` was in `System32`, the program threw an exception that the exe wasn't found.
I also entered a full path for the `RemoteAppExe.exe`.